How to call a handlebar partial from href html
I have a partial template and when I call it from  ****<a class="navbar-brand" href="{{> Golfers }}”>Golfers</a>**** it is displayed automatically in the page, should I render a link instead?
thanks in advance.
jm

Something is wrong with what you are trying to do. You cannot render a partial template into an href value of an anchor tag. You need to render a link and then you need a way to handle the browser's navigation. This could be a server set-up to serve different pages, or an anchor within your single page. I think the first question you need to answer is, what do you want to happen when the user clicks this link?
